# Why is VisualVM's profiler not "seeing" all classes/methods

Tags: java, visualvm

When i profile an app using OpenJDK's visualvm tool, i can not see methods which are called for sure. I see logging messages which are produced by them. Furthermore i can run the app within Eclipse in debug mode and set breakpoints in the code (while profiling is active) which are activated when execution arrives there. When i wait there for some minutes till i resume execution, i thought i should see those paused methods in the profiler. And when i run the app with my use case to initialize and instantiate all objects which are needed in the app before i connect with the profiler, even then i can not see all methods. Furthermore i noticed that it does not count all method invocations... sometimes it only counts a few calls, when in fact there have been thousands of calls which logged to the log file.

Does anybody know why classes/methods and its invocations are not "seen" in visualvm?

I checked many times and i did not apply any filters on the profiler, so every method call, even the Java API's methods should get profiled.

I too tried with -Djava.compiler=NONE, but the only impact besides the apps runtime increase was that the profiler seemed to stop collecting data after a few seconds and never resumed/updated its statistic. 
When adding -Xint to the jvm, i can see more methods in the profiler, but it still does not show a lot of "relevant" methods.

With the behavior of visualvm, not showing classes / methods (with hotspot compiler active), not updating statistics, it looks to me that this tool is not very useful.

Did i miss something with visualvm?

I am using visualvm 1.3.8 (Build 140703); platform 20141108-debian-
with 1.7.0_95; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.95-b01, mixed mode), but the app is executed with either Java 1.6 or Java 1.7.

Comment: I have removed the "tool request" from your question, as it would make your question off topic.

Comment: Assuming that you did not (intentionally or accidentally) exclude the respective classes in the "Settings" section that you can enable in the top right of the profiler window, I don't know what this may be related to. My first guess was inlining by the JIT. I think it should not happen with `Xint`, so this may not be the case here. Otherwise, you may play with inlining-related settings in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html . Regarding the tool. consider http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html

Comment: @Marco13: no, i checked several times the exclude/include list in Settings, but there is no entry. Furthermore i removed the entry in the "Start profiling from classes" field. The flight recorder sounds nice, but i did not find it in JDK6, nor any information in the IBM J9 VM, which is used in our production systems on AIX. Anyway, i try to profile the app on a Linux environment as i have doubts that profiling on AIX using `agentlib:hprof...` during production is a good idea.

Comment: Does the problem appear *always* or only in a particular setup? That is, can you post an MCVE that others (with the same setup) can try out to observe the effect?

Comment: I don't know why this happens, but if you just want to know the number of times a particular method gets called, you can create a breakpoint in IntelliJ, disable suspend and enable logging when the breakpoint is hit. Then you can count the number of times the breakpoint being hit is logged (you can use `sort | uniq -c` in bash for that). It's not very efficient, but it works for small hit counts.

Comment: From my experience, VisualVM (and other profiling tools) works by sampling the running application every few seconds, which results in an estimate on the most called methods, instead of tracking every single invocation. The memory allocation shown by VisualVM is not accurate also, but only an estimate. If you have a method that's called thousands of times but not counted at all, maybe it's not statistically relevant in the overall execution time of the app.

Comment: @EdgarDomingues VisualVM has a "sampler", which works more or less as you describe, and a "profiler". This question refers to the "profiler".

Comment: @RobinGreen why do you think that it is useful to draw attention on a five year old question that not even the OP has commented in the last five years? It’s not even clear whether the OP still has that problem or whether it disappeared after updating visualvm, java, or the operating system.

Comment: @Holger Because I have the same problem

Comment: @RobinGreen …and you’re using the same combination of ancient software? I think, more information about your case would have been more helpful than a bounty without even mentioning that there is a recent case of the same problem.

Comment: @Holger just stumbled over my old question. There are installations which are running 10+ yrs without change, so yes, there might be people which use the same combination of ancient software nowadays. But i moved to a different field, thats why i am not using Java anymore.

Comment: @Joysn There might be installations running ten years, but when they run smoothly that long time, there’s little reason to profile them. But that’s not the point. The other user placed a bounty on your old question without adding additional information. If a question couldn’t be solved within five years, how likely is it that someone can solved it then, without additional information? And the other user didn’t even confirm to use the same software. It ended as expected, no additional information led to no answer but a wasted bounty.